# Group duplicate columns and sum the corresponding column values using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-scrubbing

I am preprocessing apache server log data. I have 3 columns ID, TIME, and BYTES. Example:

ID       TIME            BYTES

1        13:00            10

2        13:02            30

3        13:03            40

4        13:02            50

5        13:03            70

I want to achieve something like this:

ID       TIME            BYTES

1        13:00            10

2        13:02            80

3        13:03            110

Comment: `df.groupby('TIME', as_index=False).agg({'ID': 'min', 'BYTES': 'sum'})` would do.

Comment: Indeed. @Zero, can you find a dupe?

Comment: It messed up the time. The time now starts from 0:00 in some bizarre pattern. In my case, the ID doesn't really matter. So, it's just TIME and BYTES. I want the output to be like I've shown(because i'll plot a graph against TIME).  The output must be in the order of TIME as shown. What changes do you suggest, @Zero?

Comment: What is the dtype of TIME?

Comment: `df.groupby('TIME')[['BYTES']].sum().plot()`?

Comment: I ran this `server_logs["TIME"] = pd.to_datetime(server_logs["TIME"])
` to convert time.  `dtype` of TIME is `datetime64[ns]` @ScottBoston

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, newbie here. I'm trying to find the reply in bytes at all unique times. Can you please explain what exactly does this `df.groupby('TIME')[['BYTES']].sum().plot()` do?

Comment: Does it work? If it doesn't, explaining it is pointless. :p

Comment: What it does is group by unique timestamps, find the sum of BYTES for each timestamp, leaving the result with TIME as the index. After, `plot` will plot BYTES with respect to TIME. If you want to see the plot, call `plt.show()`.

Comment: If you're still getting weird results, convert TIME to a string first - `df.assign(TIME=df.TIME.astype(str).groupby('TIME')[['BYTES']].sum().plot()`.

Comment: It has been done. See my other two comments.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it works. :p

Comment: This seemed like a dupe, and your question has been solved. Cheers!

Comment: The time got weird. @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ , `df.assign(TIME=df.TIME.astype(str).groupby('TIME')[['BYTES']‌​].sum().plot()` this gave out an error. `    ax = unique_time_bytes.assign(TIME=df.TIME.astype(str).groupby('TIME')[['REPLY_IN_BYTES']‌​].sum()SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier`

Comment: Copying the code from comments is a problem. Just type it out.

Comment: But it was working earlier(without converting TIME to string). Your answer worked too. All of a sudden, it went back to weird TIME formatting.

Comment: Sounding like a data issue to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try:

```
df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'])
ax = df.groupby('TIME')['BYTES'].sum().plot()
ax.set_xlim('13:00:00','13:03:00')
```

Output:

[image]