# Seperate columns into list after applying df.groupby() in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, k-means, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

This was the original data.

ID       TIME            BYTES

1        13:00            10

2        13:02            30

3        13:03            40

4        13:02            50

5        13:03            70

I got the following data using `ax = server_logs.groupby('TIME')['REPLY_SIZE'].sum()`.

ID       TIME            BYTES

1        13:00            10

2        13:02            80

3        13:03            110

How do I seperate the the TIME and BYTES into two different lists after doing ? It doesn't seem to separate using `time = ax[0]`.

ps:I'd like to apply k means clustering using sklearn on this data after.

Comment: How about: `v = df.groupby('TIME')['BYTES'].sum(); a, b = v.index.tolist(), v.tolist()`?

Comment: No, they’re timestamp objects. You can plot them without any issues. And yes, that’s what it does. Also, what’s wrong with using pd.Series.plot? Like I suggested in your last question?

Comment: Yep. I plotted it. It works. I can't find your pd.Series.plot in my previous question. Can you please post it here?

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48013007/group-duplicate-columns-and-sum-the-corresponding-column-values-using-pandas#comment82995023_48013007

Comment: You could've just done `df.groupby('TIME')['BYTES'].sum().plot()` :p

Comment: I wanted a scatter plot. For scatter plot we need 2 input right? `plt.scatter(a,b)`. When I _plot_ a scatter plot, the x-axis(time) is very large as compared to where the actual data is. I'll put up picture. Why is that happening tho?

Comment: That seems to be a matplotlib issue, you can fix it by setting some parameter (I'm not an expert, so I have no clue which). Alternatively, pandas has a `plot.scatter` function that you can call.

Comment: `v.plot.scatter()` doesn't work. Neither does `v.plot.scatter(a, b)`. Both give an error : `AttributeError: 'SeriesPlotMethods' object has no attribute 'scatter'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer as given by @COLDSPEED.

```
v = df.groupby('TIME')['BYTES'].sum(); 
a, b = v.index.tolist(), v.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
time=ax[:,0]
bytes=ax[:,1]
```

Can you try that?

If that doesn't work, then this should

```
time=ax["TIME"]
bytes=ax["BYTES"]
```

Comment: With `time = ax[:,0]`, I got the following error `Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex`.  With `time=ax["TIME"]`, I got this error: `Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex`.